# Generating random test cases

Tags: java

I am working on a library and need to test it. There are several operations (as functions) defined in my class which can be called in any order by the client.

```
Operation1(param1, param2)
Operation2(param3)
.
.
.
OperationN(paramX, paramY, paramZ)
```

param1, param2 etc are integers/double

Now, I am thinking of writing a test code to randomize the execution of the operations, such that a sequence of M operation will be performed in random. Each time an operation is called, the parameters need to be random generated.

What is the best way to do this in Java.

Comment: If you do go down the route of randomly generated tests, it's important that they're still repeatable. Most random generators allow you to specify a seed for generating the randomness, so that if your tests produce a bug, you can then re-run the exact same tests by feeding it the same seed. Otherwise you'll be running different tests and won't know if you've actually fixed the problem.

Comment: I am planning of logging the sequence randomly generated.

Comment: that's not sufficient.  You need to be able to run *the same "random" sequence of tests* again after fixing a bug, or simply as a regression.  If the tests are truly random, you'd got no way of knowing if a given run will exercise the combination that is going to fail.

Comment: My program has a user test mode where it would read operation sequence  from a text file. After randomizing, I am planning to write out a similar file, which can be used as input again (in the user edit mode).

Comment: I am looking for some kind of "pattern" to elegantly randomize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomized tests seem attractive because they seem to allow you to avoid writing lots of separate tests.  The problem is that you can never be sure that the random sequence will hit the edge cases, etc that are likely to fail.  IMO they are not a substitute for well designed and implemented whitebox tests.

For cases like yours, I try to design a bunch of test helpers that to make it easy to construct the input data structures.  For example a simple language + parser that allows me to express the input and expected output as text, either embedded in the unit testcases or as separate files.

Comment: "you can never be sure that the random sequence will hit the edge cases" One advantage of random test data is that it gives you a chance of detecting faulty handling of edge cases for the edge cases you *didn't* think of. I agree they are no substitute for goood unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need an interface for the operation such as

```
public interface Operation {
  public void do();
}
```

Create for each operation you want to execute a class implementing the interface. The individual parameters can be passed to the constructor.

Then put all instances in a list of type operation, randomize it and iterate through it.

```
List<Operation> ops = new Vector<Operation>();
ops.add(new ...);
Collections.shuffle();
for (Operation o: ops) {
  o.do();
}
```